# Security concerns with paypal_adaptive gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the paypal_adaptive gem with Rails 3.1 to make chained payments. However, after watching http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security I've become concerned that I should perhaps add security measures to my payment request. Specifically, I don't want someone to be able to manipulate the prices of the items which I send in my request. Of course, I'm using the standard paypal_adaptive gem request:

```
pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new

data = {
"returnUrl" => "http://testserver.com/payments/completed_payment_request", 
"requestEnvelope" => {"errorLanguage" => "en_US"},
"currencyCode"=>"USD",  
"receiverList"=>{"receiver"=>[{"email"=>"testpp_1261697850_per@nextsprocket.com",     "amount"=>"10.00"}]},
"cancelUrl"=>"http://testserver.com/payments/canceled_payment_request",
"actionType"=>"PAY",
"ipnNotificationUrl"=>"http://testserver.com/payments/ipn_notification"
}

pay_response = pay_request.pay(data)

if pay_response.success?
  redirect_to pay_response.approve_paypal_payment_url
else
  puts pay_response.errors.first['message']
  redirect_to failed_payment_url
end
```

My question is: do I need to encrypt this request to prevent people from changing prices like Ryan does in his rails cast? If so, how can I manipulate this code in order to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPN validation is definitely good practice. But with regards to encrypting the variables sent across; no, that's not necessary.

The example listed on http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security uses Website Payments Standard, in which case it *is* good to encrypt it.

But Adaptive Payments is a series of server-to-server API calls (the 'Pay' API), from your server to PayPal's. The only part exposed to the buyer is the payKey, a temporary token which the buyer can't manipulate.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I'll accept this as an answer. One question though, somewhat unrelated: I've been using these API calls to access accounts in the sandbox -- do you know if I need Website Payments Pro in order to make these API calls in production? I've been trying to find the answer to this question for forever, and you seem to be knowledgeable about Paypal so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: No, you don't need Website Payments Pro; Website Payments Pro is required if you want to use the DoDirectPayment API call. For Adaptive Payments, you'll need to submit an application via https://www.x.com/ , after which you'll get an application ID back. You'll need to ensure you're passing this application ID along in the HTTP header (something you're likely already doing, now in Sandbox).

Comment: I don't use Adaptive Payments myself (I don't need chained/split payments, thus I have no need for it), but you can log a ticket with PayPal at https://www.paypal.com/dts/ to get the exact steps you need to follow to get an application live.